# Two Errors Lumped Into One - File Field Deleted - Cannot Be Found/Deleted/Recreated

Tags: entities, files, database

I'm in the process of adding more content types/cleaning up old ones on my site. Except I keep coming across an error that has another part which seems to differ from other questions posted to this site.

I deleted a field because it had become obsolete, named "Site Document Attachment" which was a file field. Now whenever I make any change to the site, this error puts it on hold:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'cocempro_portal.field_data_field_site_document_attachment' doesn't exist:
SELECT field_data_field_site_document_attachment0.entity_type AS entity_type, 
field_data_field_site_document_attachment0.entity_id AS entity_id, 
field_data_field_site_document_attachment0.revision_id AS revision_id,
field_data_field_site_document_attachment0.bundle AS bundle FROM 
{field_data_field_site_document_attachment} 
field_data_field_site_document_attachment0 WHERE (field_data_field_site_document_attachment0.field_site_document_attachment_fid 
= :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND
(field_data_field_site_document_attachment0.deleted = 
:db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1552 
[:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 0 ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_query() 
(line 652 of /home/cocempro/public_html/portal/modules/field/modules
/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).
```

And I did double check to make sure there weren't any tables named that in my MySQL database, as that happened to me once before - and the field isn't listed in my field report. And playing the easy way out, I just tried to recreate the field in the exact same way, but that came back stating that the machine name was already in use.

So where to I go from here? I'd appreciate any help anyone might be able to offer in regards to this problem, because I'm not sure where to go at all. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, in theory, be able to just remove the references to that field from the `field_config` and `field_config_instance` tables, clear caches, and then be able to recreate the field again as if it never existed.

Please do try that in a development environment first; it's also possible, in theory, that some other non-core module has a reference to that field in some way, which may either be responsible for the problem in the first place, or cause problems when you manually remove the data.

Comment: Clive - Thank you for your answer, but there is one thing I'd like to check before I continue on. I searched the entire SQL file just to be sure, and sure enough the only times they were mentioned were in those two tables. I have deleted those rows in my local development environment. The only reason why originally wanted to recreate it was to delete it and try again. So if I don't need this field, do I have to recreate it? And as long as everything appears to be working, if I uploaded this as a replacement (while backing up the older version) - would I likely be safe?

Comment: No need to recreate it if you don't need it, if the site's operating normally you should be fine